# The Project Language Level 11 is not showing for my JDK 11 on Intellij?

Tags: windows-10, java, intellij-idea

My Project SDK is 11 but my Project Language level is only up to 10? Why 11 is not showing? I tried restarting it too.

[image: My Project SDK is 11 but my Project Language level is only up to 10? Why 11 is not showing? I tried restarting it too. click on this sentence to look at a screen shot of it.]

Answer (score 3):

Which version of IntelliJ IDEA do you have?

Support for Java 11 was first added in IDEA 2018.2. I highly recommend using at least 2018.3 if you're going to be doing Java 11 development (2018.3 was released after Java 11 was released).

You can find release information and what each one supports here: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#v2018-2-java

Comment: Thanks. I didnt thought about that. I thought IntelliJ updates automatically to newer versions